# plot axis label formatting units in R

Tags: r, plot, units-of-measurement

I'm plotting photosynthetically active radiation which has units of `umol/m2/s`
I can get R to plot "PAR umol m-2" with the `u` as `mu` and `-2` in superscript using:

```
bp_m + ylab(expression(paste('PAR ',mu,'mol m')^-2))
```

where `bpm` is the rest of the plot, but I can't get it to add the `s^-1`, I've tried various forms of expressions, paste etc

Comment: `ggplot() + ylab(expression(paste('PAR ',mu,'mol m')^-2))` works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, yes that works but I want to add s^-1 at the end and I can't get it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got there - R seems to have so many different ways of doing the same thing, taking me ages to get my head around the syntax etc

```
bp_m+labs(y = ~paste("PAR ", mu, "mol m"^-2,"s"^-1)) 
bp_m+ylab(~paste("PAR ", mu, "mol m"^-2,"s"^-1)))
```

both work